# Giant inflatable laboratory in the jungle. How to find it?

Tags: ornithology, ethology, history, forestry

When I was a child (circa year 2000), I watched a documentary (in English) about some biologists doing research about jungle (perhaps Amazon). The biologists lived in a base which was a huge inflatable structure, that was resting on top of the trees. The base had some labs in it and living quarters.

I can't find anything related on Google. It's just spam about inflatable castles.

Can someone tell me what was the name of the research project from the documentary I watched?

Comment: Can you remember what language it was in, what year it was made, anything specific about what was being studied, who was in it?

Comment: It's not the BBC ["Life in the Canopy"](https://www.amazon.com/Attenborough-Life-In-The-Canopy/dp/B007QJB5NE)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about biology as defined in the [help] — specifically it isn't about a biological mechanism, process, or research technique. In addition, you are asking multiple questions, which would be reason to close even if this were on topic. Please consider reviewing the [help] starting with [ask], [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @tyersome it is about history of biology, because giant inflatable research base is a historical achievement. Also, it is a research technique of establishing a lab in a difficult environment. Also I removed the extra questions.

Comment: @user46147 if this question were to remain open, it would be helpful to know when you watched this documentary, and which country and language you watched it in.

Comment: @bob I added the info you requested.

Comment: Thank you for removing the extra questions, but I still think this is not appropriate here. There is a site for history questions — [HSM.SE] — I don't know if your question fits their criteria, so please check their help section for suitability. If you do decide to try there, please delete your question from this site before reposting because [cross-posting is impolite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/797607). Alternatively, you can request migration of this question by flagging your post for moderator intervention and explaining what you want and why. –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more intense search, I found the [following research article](https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ppp3.10125) ( https://doi.org/10.1002/ppp3.10125) by Margaret Lowman.
She discusses canopy research, stressing that forest canopy is poorly researched topic. She outlines the history of previous research on that topic, and points to the spectacular research of Frances Halle from Institut de Botanique in Montpelier.

His team managed to launch a huge effort involving inflatable rafts, slides and dirigibles, that has been named "Radeau des Cimes" (Raft of the Peaks in English).

The structure facilitated canopy sampling and hosted 50 researchers.  Over time, the inflatables have surveyed the rain forests of Cameroon, Panama, Brazil, Gabon, and Australia [copy from the article linked].

Here's a picture from radeau-des-cimes.org :
[image]

The colors of inflatables match my memories, so I consider the search a success.